# Unity text not updating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the title/description of a playing card to change by creating a card class that holds the information:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu (menuName = "Card")]
public class Card : ScriptableObject
{
    public string cardName;
    public Sprite art;
    public string cardDetail;
}
```

Then load it with another script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CardViz : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text title;
    public Text detail;
    public Image art;

    public Card card;

    private void start()
    {
        LoadCard(card);
    }

    public void LoadCard(Card c)
    {
        if (c == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        card = c;
        title.text = c.cardName;
        detail.text = c.cardDetail;
        art.sprite = c.art;
    }
}
```

I created prefab with the basic layout of a card. Then I created a new asset value in unity for a card and given it a name and detail. Then assigned it to the public valuable Card under CardViz along with the corresponding title, detail and image variable to create a new prefab but none of the text change when I drag the newly made prefab into the hierarchy. Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you setting the name and detail at runtime?  If so, where?  If you set a breakpoint in your LoadCard method what are the values of c.cardName & c.cardDetail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small typo. Your start method needs to have a capital s.

```
 private void Start()
 {
     LoadCard(card);
 }
```